# How to encode sharp sign in NSURL

Tags: objective-c, nsurl

I have this scenario that I need to send a GET http request to the remote server. I went with NSURLConnection and intercept the request in HTTPScoop.

The url format is something like this:

```
http://domain.com?key=username##somehash&url=someotherurl.com
```

I am doing it like this:

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSString alloc]init];
urlString = @"http://domain.com?key=username##somehash&url=someotherurl.com";
NSString *encodedString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString: [NSString stringWithFormat:encodedString]]; 

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"GET"];

NSURLConnection *theConnection=[[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
```

In this case I didn't escape the # sign, and the request I see in httpscoop is:

```
http://domain.com?key=username223somehash&url=someotherurl.com
```

If I escape the sharp sign to %23, it gets to something like this in httpscoop:

```
http://domain.com?key=username22523somehash&url=someotherurl.com
```

I have tried different combinations but always have issue with the sharp sign. Are there any walk-around for this? Thanks!

Comment: Pass encodedString directly to URLWithString: rather than creating a new stringWithFormat.

Answer (score 1):

replace # with %23 ([source](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html/html_url_encoding.htm)).

edit - oops, didn't see the rest of your message.  Not sure about NSURL, but I have had difficulty encoding parameters in URLs with NSURL before, too.  I ended up using [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/), which took care of all the encoding issues.  I would recommend doing the same.

Comment: I think I mentioned I did this. It doesn't escape correctly with %23.